# Divs Taking up Entire Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just recently got into HTML and CSS as a hobby, and want to try out parallax scrolling. I found a great tutorial that described exactly what I wanted to do, except for one small issue. As I am trying to reposition a logo over top of the parallax scrolling background, the div of the logo still remains at the top of the page, taking up the entire top of the page with white. I can't resize the height: 100% attribute in the global reset because when I do, the background image disappears entirely. If I try to resize the height in the other divs, the background image yet again disappears. Here is the code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    <title>Lumberjack Times | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center"><img src="Images/Lumberjack.jpg" height="100" alt="" class="centerFace"></div>

    <div class="doNotSize" id="background"></div>

    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>





    <script src="parallax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my style.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;

    height: 100%;

    z-index: 1;
}


#background {
    background-image: url("Images/Camping\ Ground.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    background-position: center center - 300;
    top: 200;
}

.center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    display:absolute;
}

.centerFace {
    height: 400px;

    display:absolute;
    margin-top:60%;

    clip-path: circle(200px at center);
}
```

And finally, the parallax script:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrollLoop, false);


var backgroundImage = document.querySelector("#background");


var xScrollPos;
var yScrollPos;


function scrollLoop(e) {
    xScrollPos = window.scrollX;
    yScrollPos = window.scrollY;

    setTranslate(0, yScrollPos * -0.2, backgroundImage);


    requestAnimationFrame(scrollLoop);
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, element) {
    element.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "px, 0";
}
```

All very basic documents, but I cannot for the life of me find the issue! Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[Image of the issue stated, top white box displays over the entire page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHAaA.jpg)

My main guess as to why this is happening is because I'm stating that all elements should have a height of 100% of the webpage, but if I do not do this, the background image does not show. I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am a little confused...where is the logo? Is it the `.center` Lumberjack image?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro yes, the logo is the .center lumberjack image, it is placed inside of a div with the class center because I wanted to align it to the center of the page. The image in the class .doNotSize is the image I want to have be the background, parallax scrolling image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you could update your question to include a link to the tutorial you are using. It helps to better understand the desired behaviour.

Also, the code you posted could be a little bit better (as far as CSS and HTML structure), but maybe that's how the tutorial goes...

That said, I believe that's what you are trying to achieve:

Change your `.center` and `.centerFace` classes to this:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
}

.centerFace {
    height: 400px;
    clip-path: circle(200px at center);
}
```

---

#### Quick explanation

On your `.center` class, `display:absolute;` is not a valid CSS attribute. You probably wanted **position** to be `absolute`. Also, you "can't" have the same attribute twice. Your `display: flex;` was overriding the other `display` attribute.

(Usually, you will use the `display` attribute to define the behaviour of that element's children, not the position itself.)

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/824bgoyd/).